# How to add two or more numbers and display the sum (Netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans

So i'm a beginner and I am trying to figure out how to add more than 2 numbers and display it through the output of netbeans. Its really confusing for me since i'm still new to programming.

Comment: Better spend time on reading and learning. People here will confuse to hell, you don't know!

Comment: type 'java program to add two numbers' into google

Comment: More than two numbers...I did search "how to add two numbers" but it doesn't tell me how to add more than two numbers.

Comment: Read the tutorials and the Java books, one page at a time.

Comment: what do you mean display it through the output of netbeans? do you mean console?

Comment: Yes the console. I know how to add two numbers but i don't know how to add more than two numbers...i did do my studying but it doesn't tell me how to add more than 2, I just want to go deeper...

Comment: This has to be a troll post. No one who can use the internet seriously does not understand how to add more than two numbers, can they? Really?

Comment: 1+2=3
1+2+3=6
It's obvious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to define variable.

what is variable?

> A variable provides us with named storage that our programs can
>   manipulate.

There are different type variable in Java like `int`, `double`, `char`, `String`, and so on.

What do I mean by type variable?

> 1. determines the size and layout of the variable's memory
> 2. he range of values that can be stored within that memory
> 3. the set of operations that can be applied to the variable

How to define Variable in Java

> data type variable [ = value][, variable [= value] ...] ;

For example , you can define two variable as int type as follows

```
int firstNumber = 1;
int secondNumber = 2;
```

Note if you like you can define more than two variables by following up the rules.

you can do Arithmetic Operators on your variables

```
Operator    Description
  +         Additive operator (also used for String concatenation)
  -         Subtraction operator
  *         Multiplication operator
  /         Division operator
  %        Remainder operator
```

Here you want to add so you need to use `+` operator.

read this which is my source : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

At the end, you should define a variable that carries the summation of two variables like

```
int sum = number1 + number2;
```

and print the value on your console by using `System.out.print/ln`

```
System.out.print("the summation of number one and number two is " + sum);
```

Source:

1. http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_int_variables.html
2. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm

Answer (score -1):

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int d = a + b + c;
System.out.println(d);
```

If you want to add up the numbers in an array or collection:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };
int sum = 0;
for (int number : numbers) {
  sum += number;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: lol so at least through some explanation so the OP can learn something.

Comment: It's unclear how much (or little) OP knows.  I'm not going to write a tutorial on variables and output, but I retracted my "too broad" close vote to at least post some code that does what the question asked for.  Any introductory Java material should answer whatever questions OP may have about this code.